# How deploy spring cloud data flow on docker

Tags: docker, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I use the https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/tree/master/spring-cloud-dataflow-app-launcher ,

OS: ubuntu 15.10

then

```
$ mvn package docker:build
$ docker-compose up
```

but meet errors :

```
    timesource_1 | java.lang.IllegalStateException: No 'Start-Class' manifest entry specified in jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/stream/module/time-source/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/time-source-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/
timesource_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.Archive.getMainClass(Archive.java:57)
timesource_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getMainClass(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:69)
timesource_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:61)
timesource_1 |  at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.app.launcher.ModuleJarLauncher.launch(ModuleJarLauncher.java:47)
timesource_1 |  at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.app.launcher.ModuleLauncher.launchModule(ModuleLauncher.java:238)
timesource_1 |  at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.app.launcher.ModuleLauncher.launchIndividualModules(ModuleLauncher.java:228)
timesource_1 |  at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.app.launcher.ModuleLauncher.launch(ModuleLauncher.java:100)
timesource_1 |  at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.app.launcher.ModuleLauncherRunner.run(ModuleLauncherRunner.java:67)
timesource_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:806)
timesource_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:790)
timesource_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:777)
timesource_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
timesource_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
timesource_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
timesource_1 |  at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.app.launcher.ModuleLauncherApplication.main(ModuleLauncherApplication.java:45)
timesource_1 |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
timesource_1 |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
timesource_1 |  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
timesource_1 |  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
timesource_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
timesource_1 |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is my method error？  Or how to deploy on docker ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi, I've tried a method, and it worked for me. 
Maybe it will help you:

- Download [docker toolbox for windows](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/)
- Download the  [docker-credential-wincred archive](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases)
- Decompress the archive and put the executable in the docker file
- Download the last version of Spring Cloud Data Flow Local-Server's Docker Compose artifact (a link in the [home page](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/))
- Launch the Docker's terminal and with it, go to the directory that contained the docker-compose.yml file
- Type : docker-compose up
- On a browser go to the page:  MachineDockerIPAdress:9393/dashboard
  (To find out the machine docker ip adress, you should type in the docher's terminal : docker-machine ip)